# Does Microsoft hate firefox? ASP.Net gridview performance in firefox bug?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

Could someone please explain the significant difference in speed between a firefox updatepanel async postback and one performed in IE?

Average Firefox Postback Time For 500 objects: 1.183 Second

Average IE Postback Time For 500 objects: 0.295 Seconds

Using firebug I can see that the majority of this time in FireFox is spent on the server side. A total of 1.04 seconds.

Given this fact the only thing I can assume is causing this problem is the way that ASP.Net renders its controls between the two browsers.

Has anyone run into this problem before?

VB.Net Code

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetStockList() As StockList
        Dim res As New StockList

        For l = 0 To 500
            Dim x As New Stock With {.Description = "test", .ID = Guid.NewGuid}
            res.Add(x)
        Next

        Return res
    End Function


    Public Class Stock
        Private m_ID As Guid
        Private m_Description As String

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

        Public Property ID() As Guid
            Get
                Return Me.m_ID
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Guid)
                Me.m_ID = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Description() As String
            Get
                Return Me.m_Description
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me.m_Description = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

    Public Class StockList
        Inherits List(Of Stock)

    End Class
```

Markup

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">

function timestamp_class(this_current_time, this_start_time, this_end_time, this_time_difference) { 
        this.this_current_time = this_current_time;
        this.this_start_time = this_start_time;
        this.this_end_time = this_end_time;
        this.this_time_difference = this_time_difference;
        this.GetCurrentTime = GetCurrentTime;
        this.StartTiming = StartTiming;
        this.EndTiming = EndTiming;
    }

    //Get current time from date timestamp
    function GetCurrentTime() {
        var my_current_timestamp;
        my_current_timestamp = new Date();      //stamp current date & time
        return my_current_timestamp.getTime();
        }

    //Stamp current time as start time and reset display textbox
    function StartTiming() {
        this.this_start_time = GetCurrentTime();    //stamp current time
    }

    //Stamp current time as stop time, compute elapsed time difference and display in textbox
    function EndTiming() {
        this.this_end_time = GetCurrentTime();      //stamp current time
        this.this_time_difference = (this.this_end_time - this.this_start_time) / 1000; //compute elapsed time
        return this.this_time_difference;
    }

//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var time_object = new timestamp_class(0, 0, 0, 0); //create new time object and initialize it   

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        var elem = args.get_postBackElement();
        ActivateAlertDiv('visible', 'divAsyncRequestTimer', elem.value + '');
        time_object.StartTiming();
    }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        ActivateAlertDiv('visible', 'divAsyncRequestTimer', '(' + time_object.EndTiming() + ' Seconds)');
    }
    function ActivateAlertDiv(visstring, elem, msg) {
        var adiv = $get(elem);
        adiv.style.visibility = visstring;
        adiv.innerHTML = msg;
    }
</script>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="click" />
    </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            <div id="divAsyncRequestTimer" style="font-size:small;">
            </div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                        SortExpression="Description" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
                SelectMethod="GetStockList" TypeName="WebApplication1._Default">
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </form>
```

Comment: BTW: Im using Firefox 3.6.3 and IE: 8.0.7600

Comment: You nailed it. Look at the code in reflector, and you'll see that they Sleep the response thread for one second if the user is running Firefox, (the method IsDetestableBrowser returns true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing its the initial time to compile the page.  When I run the IE page first it renders in a second and subsequently running the page in firefox takes about .2 seconds.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a compile thing. My results do not match yours. They are consistent as detailed above thru multiple postbacks. I will try it on another machine right now.

Comment: On a development server my results now match yours... My bad!
Firefox renders it quicker now in my case also (does Microsoft love firefox? lol) but I can record a video of my dev environment behaving as described.... Agggh so annoying... Sorry to all!!